# Cross Platform Unified Endpoint Manager for Windows, Ubuntu and Mac OS?

Tags: windows, linux, macos, sysadmin

I'm currently looking for a good UEM like ManageEngine or Jump Cloud. I found Jump Cloud better but it doesn't offer support to linux machines ... Is there any service that offers cross platform support?

I mainly need to be able to perform patch management, restrict software, control user accounts and enforce disk encryption.